# Pass struct or class to WCF Web Service using browser

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm creating WCF Web Service, which should be consumed by applications using URL only (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/TestMethod?s=testString`).
I have successfully hosted this web service, it works well etc. But for now, I'm passing only simple values there.
For example, having next example

```
[DataContract]
public struct Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
}

//in service interface
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke]
void RegisterUser(Person newUser);
```

How should I call `RegisterUser` using URL? How will stucture parameter look? Or should I simply decompose data type to simple variables and pass them as parameters?

Comment: Take advantage of Fiddler tab Compose in order to send request without creating client.

Comment: Well, that's not actually answer i'm looking for, but thx for useful hint!

Answer (score 1):

Set Uri template to the method, so that service identify the method to execute and understand the data passed via URL.

Have a look at documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

For passing complex type pass json string (prefer post rather than get) and user serializer to deserialize the string to person object.

or Consider different requestType https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.requestformat(v=vs.110).aspx